# Swift encode UInt8

Tags: arrays, swift, numbers, nscoding

Why is it possible to encode an array of `Int` using `aCoder.encodeObject(myIntArray, forKey: "myKey")` but you get a compiler error when trying to encode an array of `UInt8` values? Conversion is actually not dramatic but I would have 56 unnecessary Bits to encode...

Comment: UInt8 might derive from objective c and isnt a subclass of an encodable object, unless you have a ton ints I dont see a problem with using the native swift type.

Comment: BTW, how do you convert it with only 56bits(7bytes)? The shortest way of as far as I can come up with is `.map{Int($0)}`, 13bytes.

Comment: @rintaro I didn't mean the array but the UInt8 type compared to Int

Comment: Oh, I see :) then, you should convert `[UInt8]` to `NSData` maybe?

Comment: @rintaro same problem

Comment: @OliverBorchert Why? Could you see the updated answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`encodeObject(_:forKey:)` in `NSCoder` accept `AnyObject?` type:

```
func encodeObject(_ objv: AnyObject?, forKey key: String)
```

So if you pass an array of `Int` to `encodeObject`, it is implicitly converted to `NSArray` of `NSNumber`s. This mechanism is explained in [the document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_48):

> When you bridge from a Swift array to an `NSArray` object, **the elements in the Swift array must be `AnyObject` compatible**. For example, a Swift array of type `[Int]` contains `Int` structure elements. The `Int` type is not an instance of a class, but because the `Int` type bridges to the `NSNumber` class, the `Int` type is `AnyObject` compatible. Therefore, you can bridge a Swift array of type `[Int]` to an `NSArray` object.

On the other hand `UInt8` is *not* `AnyObject` compatible:

> All of the following types are automatically bridged to `NSNumber`:
>
> - Int
> - UInt
> - Float
> - Double
> - Bool

Thats why you can't pass `[UInt8]` to `encodeObject(_:forKey:)`. You must convert it manually.

---

If you are concerned about encoded data size, you should use `NSData` or raw bytes array instead of `NSArray`. Actually, it depends on which `NSCoder` are you using, but for example `NSKeyedArchiver`:

```
// NSData
class Foo: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var _array: [UInt8]
    init(array:[UInt8]) {
        _array = array
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let arrayData = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("array") as NSData
        _array = Array(
            UnsafeBufferPointer(
                start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(arrayData.bytes),
                count: arrayData.length
            )
        )
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(
            NSData(bytes: _array, length: _array.count),
            forKey: "array"
        )
    }
}

// bytes
class Bar: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var _array: [UInt8]
    init(array:[UInt8]) {
        _array = array
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        var arrayLength:Int = 0
        var buf = aDecoder.decodeBytesForKey("array", returnedLength: &arrayLength)
        _array = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf, count: arrayLength))
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeBytes(_array, length: _array.count, forKey: "array")
    }
}

// NSArray of NSNumber
class Baz: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var _array: [UInt8]
    init(array:[UInt8]) {
        _array = array
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        _array = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("array") as [NSNumber]).map({ $0.unsignedCharValue })
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(_array.map({NSNumber(unsignedChar:$0)}), forKey:"array")
    }
}
```

then:

```
let array = [UInt8](0 ..< 255)
let foo = Foo(array: array)
let bar = Bar(array: array)
let baz = Baz(array: array)

let fooData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(foo)
let barData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(bar)
let bazData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(baz)

fooData.length // -> 539
barData.length // -> 534
bazData.length // -> 3,454

let fooCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(fooData) as Foo
let barCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(barData) as Bar
let bazCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(bazData) as Baz
```

`NSArray` is about 7x space consuming.